# Mozzarella problems

Tags: mozzarella

Ive tried to make mozzarella a couple of times now and have had the same problem. I heat the milk to 90 then add citric acid and stir gently. The milk then curdles and when I add the rennet the curds do not come together and I am left with loads of small clumps of curds. All the recipes and you tube videos I have read/watched show a nice smooth curd that is the cut.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of milk are you using? Is it pasteurized? Homogenized?

Comment: What recipe are you following?  Link?  It sounds like you're adding way too much acid.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not using UHT milk?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the cheesemaking.com recipe, and realised I got my conversions wrong was using about 2 liters of full fat milk not 4 so have over double the amount of citric acid. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Your ratios need to be right for sure, but GdD and FuzzyChef are asking a key question.  Ultra High Temp pasteurization and heavy homogenization raises havoc on making cheese.  I have personally given up until I can get raw milk.

Comment: Mark: since you've been having trouble, I'd also suggest getting some Ph strips or even a Ph meter, to make sure that you're acidifying it to the correct degree: Ph 5.2 to 5.4